# Why does the Maybe type wrap its value in a list?

Tags: haskell, ghci, option-type

I'm going through [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), great book, and I'm at the chapter on typeclasses. Here's the question. In GHCi when I enter

```
fmap (++ "String to be appended to") ("I am a basic string, not a type constructor")
```

I get the error

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: [[Char]]
  Actual type: [Char]
In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely
  ‘("I am a basic string, not a type constructor")’
```

I understand why I'm getting this error (because a functor requires a type constructor with a value like `Just "I am a value being passed to the Maybe type constructor"` but I don't understand why the error reads expected type `[[Char]]` is the Maybe type actually wrapping the value in a list? What's the deal?

Comment: What does that expression have to do with `Maybe`?

Comment: When I posted the question I also had the way of writing it which didn't have the error: ( Just "I am a basic string...") so the original (pre-edited) question was wondering why the expected type which was a Just "something" would be wrapped in [ ].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List `[]` is a functor too. GHC unifies `fmap` to be on lists, and deduces from the first argument that its type is `fmap :: (String -> String) -> [String] -> String`:

```
λ Prelude > :t (fmap :: (String -> String) -> [String] -> [String]) (++ "String to be appended to")  ("I am a basic string, not a type constructor")

<interactive>:1:88:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [String]
    Actual type: [Char]
```

But you probably expect `fmap` to be specialised to `fmap :: (String -> String) -> Maybe String -> Maybe String`, which would give a different error message:

```
λ Prelude > (fmap :: (String -> String) -> Maybe String -> Maybe String) (++ "String to be appended to")  ("I am a basic string, not a type constructor")

<interactive>:11:96:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe String’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the second argument of ‘fmap ::
                                 (String -> String) -> Maybe String -> Maybe String’, namely
      ‘("I am a basic string, not a type constructor")’
```

Sometimes GHC doesn't get our intentions, and finds the "wrong" cause of our error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you simply add a `Just`:

```
fmap (++ "xyz") (Just "another string")
```

results in: `Just "another stringxyz"`